# Angularjs Custom Directive not changing DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

### Use ng-if in Angularjs Directive

I have a `showTaskDetailView$` stream that I can subscribe to and I can push a boolean value through it.

```
angular.module('Project').directive('something', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>something: {{toggleValue}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        link() {
            something();
            function something() {
                showTaskDetailView$.subscribe(value => {
                    let toggleValue = value;
                    console.log(toggleValue);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

When I run this directive and I change the `showTaskDetailView$` value I see the new value in my console.log. But nothing is happening in the DOM.

Comment: Because `toggleValue` is a local variable inside the context of the `subscribe` callback.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Any suggestions how to make the `toggleValue` available outside subscribe?

Comment: Use a component with a controller. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: I see that you have 29 Angular 2+ questions. Is it possible you are trying to solve an Angular 2+ problem? The example in your question is AngularJS. AngularJS directives and components do not work with Angular 2+.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toggleValue` is a local variable and not binded to `$scope`. For DOM to update you need to add `toggelValue` on `$scope`.

Change your link function to:

```
link(scope) {
        something();
        function something() {
            showTaskDetailView$.subscribe(value => {
                scope.toggleValue = value; <-------------
                console.log(scope.toggleValue);
            });
        }
    }
```

Now you should see the updated DOM. Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):